# Use string as JS file that declares a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a plugin ([react-simple-code-editor](https://github.com/satya164/react-simple-code-editor/)) thar allow me to edit a complete JS file from the `imports` untils the end of a component declaration.

[image: react simple code editor]

This editor returns a string with all the file declaration. In this example, it would be:

```
import React from "react"; import ReactDOM from "react-dom"; function App() { return ( <h1>Hello world</h1> ); } export default App;
```

Is there a way to use this string, as code. I Mean, render it, or read it like if it is a normal file ?

I've tried [react-jsx-parser](https://github.com/TroyAlford/react-jsx-parser), but it only works with strings that **are** the component, not complete JS files.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). `eval()` will run its input (type string), as if it were part of the program:

```
string = "import React from 'react'; import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; function App() { return ( <h1>Hello world</h1> ); } export default App;";
eval(string);
```

You will notice that the MDN docs include a warning not to use `eval` for security reasons. This is because it executes the code with all the permissions the user has granted the webpage, so if there is a chance that someone evil could have modified the string, then they can run whatever code they want on the client's device. This is only an issue for certain use cases, though, and probably not yours. See ["How evil is eval?"](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/). It is also slightly slow due to the fact that the code must be compiled, but for your example this won't really be noticeable.

Comment: Thanks Leaf the legend. I should keep it as safe as posible. And eval doesn't look as the safest option.